# Datarow not returning the exact number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datarow

Whenever I run this query in MySql, it always returns 3 rows with the same ID, but different records, but in my code, it only returns 1 row.

Here's my code:

```
public DataTable DBSelect(string commandSelect)
{
    try
    {
        var sqlComm = new MySqlCommand();
        var sql

        DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        clsGlobals.gvConnMy = null;
        if (clsGlobals.gvConnMy == null)
        {
            clsGlobals.gvConnMy = CreateConnection(clsGlobals.gvstrConnString);
        }

        if (clsGlobals.gvConnMy.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            clsGlobals.gvConnMy.Open();
        }
        sqlComm = clsGlobals.gvConnMy.CreateCommand();
        sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlComm.CommandText = commandSelect;
        dt.Load(sqlComm.ExecuteReader());
        sqlComm.Dispose();
        return dt;
```

[image]

Comment: If you run the sql manually do you get 3 rows (I.E. is it a sql problem or a c# problem).

Comment: yes, it shows 3 rows like the image attached in this post. But in datarow. Only 1

Comment: I suspect `commandSelect` is not what is in your screen shot.

Comment: Im using the exact same query as what i have in the screen shot. :(

Comment: In line 6, is "var sql" supposed to not have a semicolon after it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) I believe that that is the normal behaviour.

> "The Loadmethod consumes the first result set from the loaded IDataReader, and after successful completion, sets the reader's position to the next result set, if any."

I think that you have to iterate until all records are loaded.

Comment: i dont get it. how and why  is it not returning all the rows its supposed to return?

Comment: I think that it does but I think that you need to do something like:

`while (reader.HasRows)
 {
    dt.Load...
 }
`

Comment: @AngeloSanchez did you try like this? `MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); try { while (myReader.Read()) { Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ", " + myReader.GetString(1)); } } finally { // always call Close when done reading. myReader.Close(); }` from [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the dt.Load to sqlDataReader.Fill.